# Is Arjun incarnation of Shiva ? Is this written anywhere explicitly?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, krishna, arjuna

There are too many things that indicates Arjuna is the  avtara of shiva.

Like -

1. Krishna and Arjun are friends , Vishnu and Shiva are also friends.
2. Arjun marries Subhadra , sister of Krishna . Parvati (wife of Shiva) is sister of Vishnu.(Biggest similarity) . Also Subhadra is probably avatar of Durga. Is this is correct , then Arjun is definitely Shiva as only Shiva can marry Durga.
3. Shiva is called PinakPani , i.e. someone who holds bow named Pinak . Pinak is the first bow. Arjun is the best Dhanurdhari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, partially,  as per the Skanda Purāṇa.

> [Chapter 49](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423787.html), Section 1 - Pūrvārdha, Book 4 - Kāśī-khaṇḍa, Skanda
> Purāṇa
>
> उमापि च जगद्धात्री द्रुपदस्य महीभुजः । यजतो वह्निकुंडाच्च
> प्रादुश्चक्रेति सुंदरी ॥ ४ ॥ **पंचापि पांडुतनयाः साक्षाद्रुद्रवपुर्धराः**
> । अवतेरुरिह स्वर्गाद्दुष्टसंहारकारकाः ॥ ५ ॥
>
> > Umā, the mother of the universe, also manifested herself as a very
> > beautiful lady (Draupadī) from the sacrificial fire pit of king
> > Drupada. **The five sons of Pāṇḍu (Pāṇḍavas) were the embodied forms of
> > Rudra taking incarnations on the earth from heaven for the destruction
> > of the wicked ones.**
>
> English Translation by G.V Tagare

Some dubious sources on the internet, also give the following verses, said to be part of the Rudrayamala Tantra, placing **Arjuna to have manifested from the Aghora form of Shiva.**

> ईशानं धर्मदेवोक्तं भीमं तत्पुरुषं तथा ।
> **अघोरमर्जुनं** चैव नकुलं वामदेवकम् ॥ सहादेवं तु सद्यानां पांडवं भावयेत् सदा ॥

But, I personally can't trace the above verses to any text.

Answer (score 0):

No.

1. Krishna and Arjun are friends , Vishnu and Shiva are also friends.

Ans. No. Krishna and Arjuna both were incarnations of lord Vishnu alone. They were the Rishis Nara and Narayana in their past births.

2. Arjun marries Subhadra , sister of Krishna . Parvati (wife of Shiva) is sister of Vishnu.(Biggest similarity) . Also Subhadra is probably avatar of Durga. Is this is correct , then Arjun is definitely Shiva as only Shiva can marry Durga.

Ans. Subhadra was a normal human. Not a goddess. She is never described as a goddess anywhere in mahabharata.

3. Shiva is called PinakPani , i.e. someone who holds bow named Pinak . Pinak is the first bow. Arjun is the best Dhanurdhari.

Ans. Again as described earlier, Arjuna is directly stated to be an incarnation of Lord Vishnu.